# Using PowerShell as a CGI binary in IIS Express

Tags: c#, powershell, iis, cgi, iis-express

I'm trying to use PowerShell as a CGI binary from IIS Express. I got it to work, but with a silly work-around that I don't particularly like. I'd like to understand why that work-around is needed.

Here's a simple `cgi.ps1` file that I'm using to try this out:

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK`r`nContent-Type: text/plain`r`n`r`n"

Get-ChildItem env:
```

Along with this `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PowerShell CGI" path="*.cgi" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="&quot;%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe&quot; -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\PowerShellCGI\App\cgi.ps1"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then, after starting IIS Express in this directory, and navigating to `http://localhost:8080/hello.cgi`, I get an error:

> **HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway**
>   The specified CGI application
>   misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The
>   headers it did return are "".

I had a look with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), and powershell.exe does, in fact, launch with the correct arguments. The IIS Express trace log files reveal an exit code of 0, but nothing in the output stream. The weird thing is, when launched from IIS Express, powershell.exe never even reads my ps1 file; I can see the file being read if I manually use the same command line while capturing events with Process Monitor.

Next, I tried to see if a plain cmd.exe batch script could be used as a CGI script. That works just fine; here's the simple cgi.cmd that I used:

```
@echo off
echo HTTP/1.1 200 OK
echo Content-Type: text/plain
echo.
echo Hello, World!
```

Hmm... What if I start powershell.exe from within the cgi.cmd script? That didn't work either -- all of the output from the cmd script gets returned to IIS Express; the PowerShell output is still lost somewhere.

However, what's interesting is that when I did this (call PowerShell from the cmd script), there is a PowerShell window that flashes on every page refresh. **So it looks like PowerShell does execute my script, just in a new window, so the stdin/stdout is not connected to the CGI in IIS.**

What if I use `start /b powershell.exe ...` in the cmd script? That didn't make a difference.

What if I set `system.webServer/cgi/createCGIWithNewConsole = true` in IIS Express configuration? That didn't work either, but it did have the effect of having a PowerShell console pop up with every request.

### The Workaround

I figured the issue is that powershell.exe wants a console to itself, and when it starts a new console, the input and output redirection is no longer hooked up to the new console.

This is how I finally got it to work: I wrote a thin wrapper that launches powershell.exe, and redirects stdio, stdout, and stderr.  Here's the complete Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PowerShell_CGI
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                Arguments = String.Join(" ", args),
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };

            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(e.Data);
            };

            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();

            process.StandardInput.Write(Console.In.ReadToEnd());

            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with this line in my `web.config`, everything works just fine:

```
<add name="PowerShell-CGI" path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\PowerShellCGI\App\PowerShell-CGI.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Users\Nikhil\Documents\GitHub\PowerShellCGI\App\cgi.ps1" />
```

My question is: why is this silly workaround needed? My program is simply executing powershell.exe with the same arguments, the same stdio, the same stdout, and the same stderr that it gets. I suspect that it might have to do with the `CreateNoWindow` flag; but isn't `start /b` doing the same thing? How come my little wrapper program can redirect input and output from powershell.exe just fine, but the CGI module in IIS Express cannot?

Corollary question: how can I use powershell.exe as a CGI binary, without any hacks to make it work? I'd like to see it work as simply as cmd.exe does.

Comment: A couple of ideas: (1) Add this to your PS script `[System.Diagnostics.Debug]::Write('got here')`, and see if that message appears in Sysinternals DbgView.exe. That will tell you if your script is actually running. (2) Could it be that IIS is running the x86 version of PS? Trying doing `Set-ExecutionPolicy` in both the x64 and x86 versions of PS.

Comment: Oh, I see you are setting the execution policy in the command line.

Comment: More ideas (I'm just throwing ideas out there): Your script will be outputting the text in 16bit unicode I think, but the browser might be expecting an 8bit encoding. Also, you could try connecting to localhost:8080 with PuTTY in telnet mode, and see what comes back.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! 1. I already tried adding in a write to file command in my script. Runs fine when executed directly; never runs when run from inside IIS Express. Like I mentioned, ProcMon shows that the script file isn't even read when IIS Express calls powershell.exe; it is read when run directly. 2. Execution policies are set on the cmd line, like you noticed. 3. IIS Express gets nothing at all. I tried sending various kinds of junk, and IIS Express reports what it got, so it's not a Unicode/8-bit issue.

Comment: And for #4: I see a nicely formatted IIS HTTP error page in the browser, so I don't think connecting via PuTTY will return anything else.

Answer (score 5):

If somebody is intrested, I had the same problem and was able to solve it with the following config on IIS 8.5.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="PowerShell CGI" path="*.ps1" verb="GET,POST,HEAD" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File &quot;%s&quot; %s" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```